# Change UTC0 to UTC +1/+2

Tags: php

I got a timestamp from my SQL-database: `$DBdata = '2019-10-10 12:25:59'`, this date is `UTC+0`. Well i live in Denmark where we have the following UTC.

Central EU time winter **(UTC+1)**

Central EU summertime **(UTC+2)**

These UTC's changes from summer to winter different dates each year.

**Summer time**

• 2019 - The night between Saturday 30 March and Sunday 31 March

• 2020 - The night between Saturday 28 March and Sunday 29 March

• 2021 - The night between Saturday, March 27 and Sunday, March 28

• 2022 - The night between Saturday 26 March and Sunday 27 March

• 2023 - The night between Saturday, March 25 and Sunday, March 26

**Winter time**

• 2019 - The night between Saturday, October 26 and Sunday, October 27

• 2020 - The night between Saturday, October 24 and Sunday, October 25

• 2021 - The night between Saturday, October 30 and Sunday, October 31

• 2022 - The night between Saturday 29 October and Sunday 30 October

• 2023 - The night between Saturday 28 October and Sunday 29 October

Would it be possible to make an if-statement that changes these UTC's, with the right +1/+2?
Maybe something like this:

```php
$Winter= gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("WinterUTC"));
$Summer= gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("SummerUTC"));

if (($$DBdata>= $Winter) && ($$DBdata<= $Summer)){
    $gmt_dateWinter = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date + '+ 2 hours') );
}else{
    $gmt_dateSummer = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date + '+ 1 hours') ); 
}
```

I don't know if this even is a smart way to do this. If there is another more smart way to do it please lead me in another direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the DateTime class you can easy convert a date/time to any other time zone.

```
function convertTimeZone($strDateTime, $sourceTimeZone, $targetTimeZone){
  return date_create($strDateTime, new DateTimeZone($sourceTimeZone))
    ->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($targetTimeZone))
    ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

example with a daylight saving time

```
$localTime = convertTimeZone('2019-10-10 12:25:59', 'UTC', 'Europe/Copenhagen');
echo $localTime."<br>";
```

returns:

```
2019-10-10 14:25:59
```

example wintertime

```
$localTime = convertTimeZone('2019-02-10 12:25:59', 'UTC', 'Europe/Copenhagen');
echo $localTime."<br>";
```

returns:

```
2019-02-10 13:25:59
```

Note: Solutions based on stringtotime are not recommended because of known issues and limitations on some systems.

Comment: This is just what i was thinking! Thanks!!

Comment: Can you make it say if it's CET or CEST? after the time like: 2019-10-10 21:11:34 CEST

Comment: Use the format character T in the Format-String to add CET/CEST. p.E. 'Y-m-d H:i:s T'. see: date format parameters https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: Thanks you! I will try ;)

Comment: Important note: PHP can not look to the future. If summer time is abolished in the EU, you also need to update the PHP components!

Comment: My timestamp are always more than 1min old, so i never show times that are in the future. But thanks for the notice!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`gmdate`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) and [`date("I")`](https://php.net/date) to generate the date considering the timezone:

> gmdate: Format a GMT/UTC date/time

```
$DBdata = '2019-10-10 12:25:59';
$timezone  = +2; // (GMT +2:00) CEST (European Summer Time)
$GMdate = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($DBdata) + 3600*($timezone + date("I")));
echo $GMdate;
```

returns:

```
2019-10-10 22:25:59
```

From the [`date`](https://php.net/date) documentation:

> `I` (capital i) Whether or not the date is in daylight saving time: `1`
>   if Daylight Saving Time, `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Thats simple change in php script default timezone and then display time:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

```
    $time = date('H:i:s', time());

    $ok = date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    echo $tz = date_default_timezone_get();

    $h = new DateTime();
    echo $h->format('H:i:s'); // curr time

    $o = new DateTime($time);
    echo $o->format('H:i:s'); // time
```

Comment: Okay, i have this date: `$date = '2019-09-25 11:19:50';` and  the timezone is `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Copenhagen');`, with that date it should print out `2019-09-25 13:19:50`, but it doesn't? what am i doing wrong? i use `Y-m-d H:i:s`